# indexedDB.deleteDatabase() does not delete?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Google Chrome lists two indexed databases for my own website:

```
Ursprung:   http://www.example.com/
Größe auf Datenträger:  5,5 KB
Zuletzt geändert am:    Donnerstag, 9. April 2015 22:23:53

Ursprung:   https://www.example.com/
Größe auf Datenträger:  1.048 B
Zuletzt geändert am:    Dienstag, 3. März 2015 22:49:21
```

Regarding my research this is resulted through [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). As I do not know who set this databases and what names they have I tried to [find the names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234833/318765) and after that [delete them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15861765/318765) as follows:

```
<script>
indexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames().onsuccess = function(sender, args) {
    console.log(sender.target.result);
    var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(sender.target.result);
    req.onsuccess = function () {
        console.log("Deleted database successfully");
    };
    req.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Couldn't delete database");
    };
    req.onblocked = function () {
        console.log("Couldn't delete database due to the operation being blocked");
    };
};
</script>
```

The console shows `Deleted database successfully` but the entry in the Google Chrome website data stays. It only changes in size (between 5 and 10 kB) and the timestamp changes. The `console.log` of `sender.target.result` returned:

```
DOMStringList {length: 0, item: function, contains: function}length: 0__proto__: DOMStringList
...
```

What is wrong and how do I delete both databases through Javascript?

**Update 1**
Now I tried to create a new database on my own to find out what I need to do to delete it again. Finally this worked (for multiple databases in one step):

```
<script>
// delete all databases
window.indexedDB.webkitGetDatabaseNames().onsuccess = function(sender, args) {
    console.log(sender.target.result);
    for (var key in sender.target.result) {
        window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase(sender.target.result[ key ]);
    }
};
// create a database
//window.indexedDB.open("testDB", 1);
</script>
```

But after all this testing the Indexed Database filesize in Google Chrome raised to 105 KB:

```
Größe auf Datenträger:  105 KB
Zuletzt geändert am:    Donnerstag, 9. April 2015 23:26:27
```

It seems that the browser reserves the maximum used database size of the past altough I deleted it. Or is it possible to restore the data?

The next question is why the second database is still unchanged. Is this an other type of database? I really find it scary not having control of something that was created through my website and saved in my visitors browser.

Comment: From what you're saying about the output of `sender.target.result`, `sender.target.result[1]` would definitely not be the database name, which is the required parameter for `deleteDatabase`.

Comment: sorry this is a typo. or to say I tried both `sender.target.result` and `sender.target.result[1]`. The reason for this test was [this code](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/28891/delete-indexedDB-database). I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Chrome lists two indexed databases for my own website

Where does Chrome do that?

I suspect what you are seeing are not IndexedDB databases.