# Is it possible to clear an indexeddb in intel xdk

Tags: intel-xdk

Does anyone know if you can clear an indexeddb in Intel XDK? I know that you can update the db version to change it, but it would be nice for dev purposes if you could clear it.

I know you can do this in chrome by going to "settings" - "All cookies and site data" and then finding the site and clicking remove. Is there something similar for xdk?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Intel XDK uses JS, CSS, and HTML. So you should be able to use JS to solve this problem. This may be what you're looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861630/how-can-i-remove-a-whole-indexeddb-database-from-javascript

Comment: @DanielBrown is correct -- the XDK builds Cordova apps, so your app runs inside of a "webview" -- which is like an embedded browser. In general, most of the rules of a browser apply to a webview. On Android you should use the Crosswalk option, because the stock Android webview on Android 4.x devices is very old and limited in features.

Comment: Yeah, that should totally work too.  Was originally thinking of manually deleting it :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use `indexedDB.deleteDatabase()` in the XDK the same as in a browser as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861630/how-can-i-remove-a-whole-indexeddb-database-from-javascript).  It should work in the Emulator and App Preview (and Debug tab) as well as in your final app, should you need it there.